# Given an array A,compute B s.t B[i] stores the nearest element to the left of A[i] which is smaller than A[i]

Tags: arrays, algorithm, stack

Given an array `A[1..n]`, we want to compute another array `B[1..n]` such that `B[i]` stores the nearest element to the left of `A[i]` which is smaller than `A[i]`.
Time complexity should be `O(n)`.

(For `i>1`,If there are no such smaller elements to the left, then `B[i]` simply contains `A[i]`, and `B[1]=A[1]`.)

Example :

> input : 6,9,12,17,11
>   output:6,6, 9, 12, 9

I was thinking for implementing a stack,
put `A[1]` in `B[1]`, then push to stack.
for filling `B[i]`,compare `A[i]` with elements of stack and pop till you get smaller element.
finally push `A[i]` to stack.

Is above approach correct, and is there a cheaper solution?

Comment: You mean: 'to the *left* of A[i]'. You also have to say what you want if there is no such element (for instance, for B[1] in your example, and also for i>1 if there are no smaller elements).

Comment: The problem seems ill-defined. As TonyK pointed out, your example is not in line, and additionally, it is unclear, what B[0] should be, as there is no element in A that is smaller than 6. Please clarify the problem description first.

Comment: pl let me know if it still ambiguous.I changed right to left.i think the sequence is fine now. let B[1] be A[1] only coz there is no element left to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your stack approach is correct. It works because if you pop an element bigger than `A[i]`, that element will never be needed for any elements following `A[i]`, because you can just use `A[i]` instead.

Each element is only accessed twice, so this is `O(n)`.

Comment: nice to listen this,I am also curious about alternate solutions, which avoid stack and is cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

Stack approach isn't correct. just look what happen if you had in input 6, 9, 12, 17, 11, **15**. When you will be work with 15 your stack have been forgotten about 12 & 17. But nearest small left element of A[5] is 12.

Algorithm of Saeed isn't right too. Just try to compute.

Right answer could be something like this

```
b[1] = a[1];
s[1] = 1;
for (i=2; i<=n; i+=1) { 
  j = i - 1;
  while (j>1){
    if (a[j]<a[i]) {
      b[i] = a[j];
      s[i] = j;
      break;
    } else {
      j = s[j];
    }
  }
  if (j = 1) {
    b[i] = a[j];
    s[i] = j;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure but it has complexity O(n).

Comment: Nearest(left) of 15,which is less than it is 11 and not 12. The output of your array should be 6,6,9,12,9,11.

Comment: @Maxim Welikobratov If the problem had been to find the greatest smaller on the left of every element in the array, then the stack based approach will not work but as the problem is to find the nearest element on the left that is less than the current element, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
B[1]=A[1]
push(B[1])
for i=2 to n do
{
    while(A[i] > stack_top ANS stack_top!=NULL)
       pop()
    if(stack_top=NULL)
        B[i]=A[i]
    else
        B[i]=stack_top
    push(A[i])
}
```

As IVlad pointed out that each element is pushed and poped atmost once, time is O(n).

pl do correct me if there is some mistake, and I am curious for any alternate solution which avoids stack and is cheaper.