# Count number of swaps to sort first k-smallest element using a bubble sort like algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Given an array `a` and integer `k`. Someone uses following algorithm to get first k smallest elements:

```
cnt = 0
for i in [1, k]:
    for j in [i + 1, n]:
        if a[i] > a[j]:
            swap(a[i], a[j])
            cnt = cnt + 1
```

The problem is: How to calculate value of `cnt` (when we get final k-sorted array), i.e. the number of swaps,  in `O(n log n)` or better ?

Or simply put: calculate the number of swaps needed to get first k-smallest number sorted using the above algorithm, in less than `O(n log n)`.

I am thinking about a binary search tree, but I get confused (How array will change when increase i ? How to calculate number of swap for a fixed i ?...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very good question: it involves **Inverse Pairs**, Stack and some proof techniques.

Note 1: All index used below are **1-based**, instead of traditional **0-based**.

Note 2: If you want to see the algorithm directly, please start reading from the bottom.

First we define **Inverse Pairs** as:

> For `a[i]` and `a[j]`, in which `i < j` holds, if we have `a[i] > a[j]`, then `a[i]` and `a[j]` are called an **Inverse Pair**.

For example, In the following array:

```
3 2 1 5 4
```

`a[1]` and `a[2]` is a pair of Inverse Pair, `a[2]` and `a[3]` is another pair.

Before we start the analysis, let's define a common language: in the reset of the post, "inverse pair starting from `i`" means **the total number of inverse pairs involving `a[i]`**.

For example, for `a = {3, 1, 2}`, inverse pair starting from 1 is 2, and inverse pair starting from 2 is 0.

Now let's look at some facts:

1. If we have `i < j < k`, and `a[i] > a[k]`, `a[j] > a[k]`, swap `a[i]` and `a[j]` (if they are an inverse pair) won't affect the total number of inverse pair starting from `j`;
2. Total inverse pairs starting from i may change after a swap (e.g. suppose we have `a = {5, 3, 4}`, before `a[1]` is swapped with `a[2]`, total number of inverse pair starting from 1 is 2, but after swap, array becomes `a = {3, 5, 4}`, and the number of inverse pair starting from 1 becomes 1);
3. Given an array `A` and 2 numbers, `a` and `b`, as the head element of `A`, if we can form more inverse pair with `a` than `b`, we have `a > b`;
4. Let's denote the total number of inverse pair starting from `i` as `ip[i]`, then we have: if `k` is the min number satisfies `ip[i] > ip[i + k]`, then `a[i] > a[i + k]` while `a[i] < a[i + 1 .. i + k - 1]` must be true. In words, if `ip[i + k]` is the first number smaller than `ip[i]`, `a[i + k]` is also the first number smaller than `a[i]`;

**Proof of point 1:**

By definition of inverse pair, for all `a[k]`, `k > j` that forms inverse pair with `a[j]`, `a[k] < a[j]` must hold. Since `a[i]` and `a[j]` are a pair of inverse and provided that `i < j`, we have `a[i] > a[j]`. Therefore, we have `a[i] > a[j] > a[k]`, which indicates the inverse-pair-relationships are not broken.

**Proof of point 3:**

Leave as empty since quite obvious.

**Proof of point 4:**

First, it's easy to see that when `i < j`, `a[i] > a[j]`, we have `ip[i] >= ip[j] + 1 > ip[j]`. Then, it's inverse-contradict statement is also true, i.e. when `i < j`, `ip[i] <= ip[j]`, we have `a[i] <= a[j]`.

Now back to the point. Since k is the min number to satisfy `ip[i] > ip[i + k]`, then we have `ip[i] <= ip[i + 1 .. i + k - 1]`, which indicates `a[i] <= a[i + 1.. i + k - 1]` by the lemma we just proved, which also indicates there's no inverse pairs in the region `[i + 1, i + k - 1]`. Therefore, `ip[i]` is the same as the number of inverse pairs starting from `i + k`, but involving `a[i]`. Given `ip[i + k] < ip[i]`, we know `a[i + k]` has less inverse pair than `a[i]` in the region of `[i + k + 1, n]`, which indicates `a[i + k] < a[i]` (by **Point 3**).

You can write down some sequences and try out the 4 facts mentioned above and convince yourself or disprove them :P

Now it's about the algorithm.

A naive implementation will take `O(nk)` to compute the result, and the worst case will be `O(n^2)` when `k = n`.

But how about we make use of the facts above:

First we compute `ip[i]` using Fenwick Tree (see **Note 1** below), which takes `O(n log n)` to construct and `O(n log n)` to get all `ip[i]` calculated.

Next, we need to make use of facts. Since swap of 2 numbers only affect current position's inverse pair number but not values after (point 1 and 2), we don't need to worry about the value change. Also, since the nearest smaller number to the right shares the same index in `ip` and `a`, we only need to find the first `ip[j]` that is smaller than `ip[i]` in `[i + 1, n]`. If we denote the number of swaps to get first `i` element sorted as `f[i]`, we have `f[i] = f[j] + 1`.

But how to find this "first smaller number" fast? Use stack! Here is a post which asks a highly similar problem: [Given an array A,compute B s.t B[i] stores the nearest element to the left of A[i] which is smaller than A[i]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983886/given-an-array-a-compute-b-s-t-bi-stores-the-nearest-element-to-the-left-of-a)

In short, we are able to do this in `O(n)`.

But wait, the post says "to the left" but in our case it's "to the right". The solution is simple: we do backward in our case, then everything the same :D

Therefore, in summary, the total time complexity of the algorithm is `O(n log n) + O(n) = O(n log n)`.

Finally, let's talk with an example (a simplified example of @make_lover's example in the comment):

`a = {2, 5, 3, 4, 1, 6}`, `k = 2`

First, let's get the inverse pairs:

`ip = {1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0}`

To calculate `f[i]`, we do backward (since we need to use the stack technique):

```
f[6] = 0, since it's the last one
f[5] = 0, since we could not find any number that is smaller than 0
f[4] = f[5] + 1 = 1, since ip[5] is the first smaller number to the right
f[3] = f[5] + 1 = 1, since ip[5] is the first smaller number to the right
f[2] = f[3] + 1 = 2, since ip[3] is the first smaller number to the right
f[1] = f[5] + 1 = 1, since ip[5] is the first smaller number to the right
```

Therefore, `ans = f[1] + f[2] = 3`

**Note 1**: Using Fenwick Tree (Binary Index Tree) to get inverse pair can be done in O(N log N), here is [a post](http://pavelsimo.blogspot.sg/2012/09/counting-inversions-in-array-using-BIT.html) on this topic, please have a look :)

**Update**

Aug/20/2014: There was a critical error in my previous post (thanks to @make_lover), here is the latest update.

Comment: Neh.  I misread the code, not you.  If you make an edit, I can turn my downvote into an upvote.  (But I can't if you don't because the system stupidly trusts me not to make mistakes like this.)

Comment: could you explain how the algorithm work in this case:

n = 6, m = 2

array: 6 65 10 20 4 97

Comment: you're right, the original post has a critical bug. See the updated post :)

Comment: still got counter-example?

Comment: @nevets, sorry for late accepted, I am pretty busy this time, you know, exam exam exam...

Comment: it's ok :) all the best to your exams :D

Comment: This answer is stellar, and frankly a damn shame it is tucked way in this rather quit question on a dusty shelf of the SO archives. I hope it someday gets a little more chutzpah and a few referrals. +1.