# How to find maximum element on left hand side of an element which is smaller than the element?

Tags: java, c, arrays, algorithm, max

Suppose I have an array of integers like this:

**`{ 3, 1, 6, 8, 2, 0, 1 }`**

I need to find the maximum element on the left hand side of each element which is smaller than the element, or print `-1` if that maximum element doesn't exist. So, solution for this problem will be:

**`{ -1, -1, 3, 6, 1, -1, 0 }`**

I can solve this in `O(n^2)` using two loops. Inner loop will find maximum element which is smaller than the given element. But is there any better approach to solve this?

Comment: I think there is a mistake...maybe the solution should be `{-1, -1, 3, 6, 1, -1, 0 } instead?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: This is different than the question you mentioned. I don't think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

While this question is not about [finding the *rightmost* element on the left hand side that is smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983886/given-an-array-a-compute-b-s-t-bi-stores-the-nearest-element-to-the-left-of-a?lq=1), a problem for which there is a cute linear-time algorithm involving a stack, it is closely related. To solve this problem, sort pairs of array indexes and values by value, then run the algorithm from the linked question treating the indexes as values. This avoids the constant factors imposed by a binary search tree.

Since sorting distinct elements is linear-time reducible to this problem, the running time of O(sort(n)) is more or less optimal.

Python implementation (more subtle than expected; note that `sorted` must not rearrange elements that compare equal).

```
def alg(lst):
    indexes = sorted(range(len(lst) - 1, -1, -1), key=lst.__getitem__)
    stack = []
    out = [-1] * len(lst)
    for i in indexes:
        while stack and i < stack[-1]:
            del stack[-1]
        if stack:
            out[i] = lst[stack[-1]]
        stack.append(i)
    return out


print(alg([3, 1, 6, 8, 2, 0, 1]))
```

Comment: for the given input, indexes turns out to be [5,6,1,4,0,2,3] instead of [5,1,6,4,0,2,3], may i ask why that is the case as sorted in python is a stable sort and if latter comes, the code fails. You can also view it at here - https://onlinegdb.com/H16wzVhed.

This sol fails at online judge because of the reason i mentioned above. In case you want to verify the same at you end, here is the link - https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/smaller-on-left2036/0/?category[]=Hash&category[]=Hash&difficulty[]=1&page=1&query=category[]Hashdifficulty[]1page1category[]Hash#

Comment: @Varun We're sorting the array `[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]`, so a stable sort must put `6` before `1` because that's how it is in the initial list.

Comment: Usually i code in java and as this code is in python, i am finding it a bit confusing. I see that you are iterating the array from end to sort it according to values. But if i change it to indexes = sorted(range(0, len(lst), 1), key=lst.__getitem__), the indexes is now [5,1,6,4,0,2,3] instead of [5,6,1,4,0,2,3]. Is there a reason why you started sorting the array from right? If the array is sorted from left the produced final solution is [-1, -1, 3, 6, 1, -1, 1] and that seems to be wrong.

Comment: @Varun in some sense the sort order makes an infinitesimal perturbation to the input elements. By putting greater indices first in the order of equals, we're essentially making them compare less than the ones before them. If we did it the other way, then the perturbation would in some sense make the earlier element eligible as the maximum for the later. Instead of a stable sort you could also use (lst[i], -i) as the sort key.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the numbers that you have found so far in a tree map. Store their index along with the number. When you come to the number at index `i`, look in the tree for the highest number lower than `array[i]`. Using [`lowerEntry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#lowerEntry(K)) lets you do it in Log<sub>2</sub>N time, making the overall timing N*Log<sub>2</sub>N

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1: For the first element we can just append -1 to our answer.

2: Loop i through the first element in the list and keep adding (i - 1)th element to a Treeset.

3: To find the greatestSmaller element we can just find the lower_entry by the 
    set.lower(Element)

4: If the result is null just append -1.

Here's an implementation

```
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
    b.append(-1);
    b.append(" ");
    for(int i = 1; i<a.length; i++){
        set.add(a[i-1]);
        Integer result = set.lower(a[i]);
        if(result != null)
            b.append(result);
        else
            b.append(-1);
        b.append(" ");
    }
```